# Removing Significant Variable in the Model did not change the R^2 and AIC

Tags: regression

I removed a significant variable from the model, and expecting to get a lower adjusted R^2, but nothing has changed, even the AIC is the same even after removing the significant variable.

I am trying to get an explanation regarding this, but have not found any.

Does this mean that this "significant" variable is not really significant?

Comment: Well, what is your understanding of the technical meaning of the word "significant" here?

Comment: p value is less than .05

Comment: My guess is that another variable that was previously dropped due to perfect multicollinearity started to be included again once you dropped your “significant variable”.  You’d have to provide much more detail to get a real answer.

Comment: Well, sure, so what's the meaning of a p-value in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this question, we need to go back to the definition of significant. Perhaps a loaded word. Significant refers to the the value of the parameter for a variable, based off a F or t statistic and a p-value calculated from that statistic. The full definition would be: given the data we've observed and the parameter constructed from that data, the probability of getting a test statistic (in absolute value) larger than the one calculated (based on your data) if you were to repeat the experiment an infinite number of times.

Nothing in that definition has anything to do with statistical relationship, "fit" of the model to the data, or prediction. So we can have statistically significant parameters, and still have a poor model for predictability. The two are not synonymous. I would've expected at least a small change in AIC or R^2, but it's not out of the realm of possibilities.

Comment: @SuperSaiyan This is a good answer.  Please consider accepting it!